# Print jpeg/png images using Wifi/Bluetooth Printer from Android app

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi, printers

I have Hp Photosmart Wifi printer and I developed app for one of my product. Now I would like to add the functionality of **printing images from my app using Wifi printer**. I want to connect my app with wifi printer and for that i did some googling and found that I can do so using Socket programming as wifi has the IP address. But i am unable to find anything which can help me for printing images from android app programmatically.

Can anyone guide me how can i print images on A4 size paper with Wifi printer from my app? All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: wifi printer model pls

Comment: HP Deskjet Ink Advantage 6525 e-All-in-One Printer (CZ276B)

Comment: please refer the document or send link to that document i wil read an explain u

Answer (score 0):

I used this for blutooth

try this for wifi also

```
OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = wifiSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
os.write(("Hello").getBytes());
os.write(("printing").getBytes());
os.close();
```

for printing the image you need to send some commands before print the data,

need to convert the image to byte array and then you need to send to printer.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but would you know what commands you need to send for an image?